# How to call another function

Tags: python-3.x

i want to create a new function

```
def new_func(abc):
with open(APPROVAL_BALLOT_FILENAME) as f:
        while True:
            line = f.readline()
            if line:
                lines.append(line)
            else:
                break
```

and do 
new_func(feklfe)

how would i do that ?
when i do it , the lines does not get defined for some reason .

Answer (score 0):

You have to define `lines` properly inside the function:

```
def new_func(abc):
    lines = []
    with open(APPROVAL_BALLOT_FILENAME) as f:
    while True:
        line = f.readline()
        if line:
            lines.append(line)
        else:
            break
    return lines
```

What you probably also want, is using the filename as a parameter to your function. Like this:

```
def new_func(filename):
    lines = []
    with open(filename) as f:
    while True:
        line = f.readline()
        if line:
            lines.append(line)
        else:
            break
    return lines
```

Comment: but then in option_plurality(lines). the function option_plurality's lines get undefined then . im really really confused

Comment: Consider creating a minimalistic example. Only your `new_func` and one line to call that function and print output. Does that work for you?

Comment: i still get a global name 'lines' is not defined. but if i put everything together in one function it works

Comment: What about that minimalistic example? Does that work? You can update your question to provide that piece of code, so that others can have a look.

Answer (score 0):

Your function fails because you don't define `lines` anywhere inside it. But the main problem with your code is that you try to read a file with a while loop, which is about the worst way to read a file in python, at least if all you do with the lines is storing them in a list.

The file object already has a function returning a list of its lines, appropriately named `readlines`. Even better, the file object is an iterator over all its lines; meaning all you have to do to get a list of lines with their newlines removed is this simple expression:

```
with open(filename) as f:
    lines = [line.rstrip("\n") for line in f]
```